# Linked list delete node c++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have this linked list adt. The only problem i am having is in this remove function. I tried dry running it but can't figure it out correctly. Please someone explain it

```
void list::remove(int v)
{
    node *temp, *pre;
    temp = head;
    if(temp->data==v)
    {
        head = temp->next;
        delete temp;
        cout << endl << v << "has been deleted" <<endl;
        return;
    }
    pre = temp;
    while(temp!=0)
    {
        if(temp->data==v)
        {
            pre->next = temp->next;
            delete temp;
            cout << "\nValue deleted" <<endl;
            return;
        }
        pre = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    cout << endl << v << "not found" <<endl;
}
int main()
{
    list l;
    l.insert(8);
    l.insert(9);
    l.insert(10);
    l.display();
    cout << "After deleting" <<endl;
    l.remove(9);
    l.display();
}
```

Comment: Please describe the problem in more detail than that you have one.

Comment: Is it code issue or you just need explanation for the code?

Answer (score 1):

The code appears to be correct upon first glance. A quick explanation of it would be:You are making two node pointers, one to point to the current element on the list and one to point to the previous one. First case would be that the element you are trying to delete is in the beginning of the list(so it is the head).In this case you move head to the next element(head=temp->next) and delete the node. The other case would be that the element is somewhere in the list. Using the while loop you scan through the list (pre=temp, temp=temp->next are to move you to the next elements) and using the if condition you check if the element is the one you are looking for.

Comment: thank you for answering. I got the first part. but in second part, in the conditional block we are saving the temp->next in pre->next. 1) Why we are doing it? In the upper part of code we declared temp=head. Before while loop we stored pre=temp. Ultimately pre is also in the start of the list where temp & head are present. right?  So when we scan the list and the node is found. 2) Why we are storing q->next= p->next"?

Comment: 1) Aside from just deleting the node, we need to connect the previous node of the list to the next one, so that all the nodes remain linked to each other and the linked list doesn't "break" in two parts. So you need the pointer from the previous node to point to where the node you are about to delete pointed to. So that's why you do pre->next=temp->next.

Comment: You initialize the pre pointer to point to the head of the list so that you start scanning it, I don't understand the question. Which pointers are p and q? Also, if my answer helped, please mark it as correct.